# Liouville's Theorem. Example when the theorem does not work if $f$ is not entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm struggling with understanding Liouville's theorem, more precisely when does the theorem not hold. I'm looking for a non-holomorphic function to show that theorem doesn't work.

> Liouville’s Theorem: Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an bounded entire function.
> Then $f$ is constant.

My first guess is, I should take function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on set $|z|>1$, which is ofcourse bounded but not holomorphic in $z=0$.

I don't know how to move futher with the example or should I find another example of non-holomorphic function?

Comment: So you want a bounded but not holomorphic function that is not a constant?

Comment: I'm into why entire function assumption is essential.

Comment: The just let $f$ be $+1$ somewhere and $-1$ somewhere else.  Bounded, not constant, and not entire because it's not even continuous.

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(z)=\cos(\operatorname{Re}z)+\sin(\operatorname{Im}z)i$? It is bounded, non-holomorphic and non-constant. And, as an extra, it is continuous.